# How to replace the region text with the text of a string, without deleting and reinserting parts that are the same

Tags: replace, string, insert

In a few functions I've written logic that does the following:

```lisp
(defun replace-in-region (str beg end)
  "Replace the region between BEG & END with STR."
  (save-excursion 
    (goto-char beg)
    (delete-region beg end)
    (insert str)))
```

There is some opportunity avoid redundant work (and redundant storage in the undo-stack), by contracting the region for parts of the buffer that already match the beginning/end of the string.

There is `replace-buffer-contents` which is useful for replacing buffer contents but as far as I can tell it can't be limited to a region.

Is there a utility to do this? Or do I need to write my own?

Comment: The doc string of `replace-buffer-contents says: `Replace accessible portion of current buffer with that of SOURCE.` So you can limit the `accessible` portion of the buffer to the region with `narrow-to-region`. Untested, but I don't see any reason why it would not work.

Comment: Saw this but in my initial tests it seemed `replace-buffer-content` ignored narrowing. It turn out my test was in a `before-save-hook` which I suspect is widening the buffer, so I think this could be made into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own quiestion with a utility funciton that calls `delete-region` and `insert` with additional checks for matching beginning & end.

```el
(defun my-buffer-replace-region (str beg end)
  "Replace region from BEG to END with STR."
  (let ((len (length str))
        (i-beg nil)
        (i-end nil)
        (i-end-ofs nil))

    ;; Check for skip end.
    (let ((i 0))
      (let ((len-test (min (- end beg) len)))
        (while (< i len-test)
          (let ((i-next (1+ i)))
            (cond
             ((eq (aref str (- len i-next)) (char-after (- end i-next)))
              (setq i i-next))
             (t ;; Break.
              (setq len-test i))))))
      (unless (zerop i)
        (setq i-end (- len i))
        (setq len (- len i))
        (setq end (- end i))
        (setq i-end-ofs i)))

    ;; Check for skip start.
    (let ((i 0))
      (let ((len-test (min (- end beg) len)))
        (while (< i len-test)
          (cond
           ((eq (aref str i) (char-after (+ beg i)))
            (setq i (1+ i)))
           (t ;; Break.
            (setq len-test i)))))
      (unless (zerop i)
        (setq i-beg i)
        (setq beg (+ beg i))))

    (when (or i-beg i-end)
      (setq str (substring str (or i-beg 0) (or i-end len))))

    (goto-char beg)
    (delete-region beg end)
    (insert str)
    (when i-end-ofs
      ;; Leave the cursor where it would be if the end wasn't clipped.
      (goto-char (+ (point) i-end-ofs)))
    (cons beg (+ beg (length str)))))
```